# Changing vscode config without changing .vscode folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm currently working on a lager project with many contributors (it's my first time) and I need to change some config options for my local development. However, the repo I'm working on already contains a .vscode folder.

Whenever I need to change e. g. the location of my python interpetor I'm changing this folder and would need to check it into version control (which I can't do since these are changes that only I need).

I'd love to have a way to overwrite these settings locally and don't know how to accomplish that without pushing my changes to the repo?

Comment: you don't need to commit EVERY file that has changed, just leave the `.vscode/settings.json` file as a modified file, if you pull and get a conflict stash the file, pull and pop the stash, you can cherry pick changes made to be committed if you change this file and others need the changes

Comment: Hm, having a weird unstaged, uncommited modification lingering in my repo would be a very undesirable situation for me (just my personal preference).

Comment: then make the modification in your User settings or create a `.code-workspace` file (Multi Root) with only this workspace and make the setting changes there. Or create a branch and make the changes to the settings there no need to push this branch and just rebase as you go along

Answer (score 0):

Excluding a file is simple. In the root folder of your source controlled project is a folder named .git. (Note the period on the front, also note that on some operating systems it may be hidden by default.) Under it is another folder called info.

In .git/info is a file called exclude (with no extension). To it, simply add the names of the files you want to exclude from source control.

**Source:** https://arcanecode.com/2021/01/11/exclude-a-file-from-git-source-code-control-in-vscode/

**Edit:** This will exclude the file you want only locally for you, if you want everyone to ignore this file then do the changes to your .gitignore file, or make one if you don't have one.

Comment: The files are already checked into version control. I don't think adding them to ignore pattern will make them untracked.